# difference between open index.html and live server

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to manipulate the SVG file based on this post [document.getElementById results in null where moving svg into object tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24129810/document-getelementbyid-results-in-null-where-moving-svg-into-object-tag) and below are my files.

index.html

```
<body>
  <object data="../svg/barplot.svg" alt='bar-graph' type="image/svg+xml" id="barplot" width="800"
    height="800">
  </object>
</body>
```

script.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    var barplot = document.getElementById("barplot");
    console.log(barplot);
    var svgDoc = barplot.contentDocument;
    console.log(svgDoc);
```

When I use the `VS Code live server`, the output of `svgDoc` is the SVG file itself and everything works perferct.

Live server (barplot)

```
<object data="../svg/barplot.svg" alt="bar-graph" type="image/svg+xml" id="barplot" width="800" height="800">
  </object>
```

Live server (svgDoc)

```
#document
<svg>
svg content
</svg>
```

However, if I use `open index.html` in the terminal and open the HTML file from the filesystem in a browser, the console output of `svgDoc` is null.

`Open index.html` (barplot)

```
<object data="../svg/barplot.svg" alt="bar-graph" type="image/svg+xml" id="barplot" width="800" height="800">
  </object>
```

`Open index.html` (svgDoc)

```
null
```

For future development, I have to use the `open index.html` method. Could someone help with this issue? Thanks

Comment: (ritwickdey) Live Server [has issues](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-server/issues/684) with SVG. Most users switched to Five Server: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yandeu.five-server

Comment: You already have the correct answer to your question, but maybe you can explain what happens when you use the open command in the terminal -- will the file open in a browser or an editor?

Comment: @chrwahl when using `open index.html` it will open in a browser, however, I can not interact with it because of the svgDoc mentioned above is a null file

Comment: For your last statement in your question: "For future development, I have to use the open index.html method." No! When you are developing your website you should run a web server locally of some kind. That could be the Live Server that you mention or something else. In any case you have two answers to your question that are both correct. Mark the one that you like the best to be the correct answer.

Comment: @chrwahl thank you so much for the explanation! Our basic logic is that users can call some functions within an open-source R package and then a website can pop out with an SVG generated by another function implemented in that package. Afterward, users can interact with SVG.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a website locally and with a server has its differences.
In local you are really restricted in what you can do or access since it is affected by CORS.
And it seems this case is one of them.
You can't access the document that is being served by the filesystem.
Things like `XMLHttpRequest` or `Fetch` API are restricted too,
you won't be able to request a local file with those.
Or get the image data of a image drawn on a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Opening with Live server means that you are serving all of your files locally on a "live-server" (your machine).

When you are opening `index.html` you are just viewing the static html page without the other files in your project. This is why your svg element is showing as `null`.

Comment: When using `open index.html`, I still can see the svg in the browser, however I can not interact with it.

Comment: This is because you need the `script.js` file to be served along side the `index.html` file in order to use your JavaScript event listener.